# java - print formatting width

Tags: java, formatting, printf

Today I learned that I can't properly format output to save my life. I've been struggling with printing two strings and an integer like this.

```
Account holder   Social security number
Steve jensen                 XXXXXXXXX
Mary Chapman                 XXXXXXXXX
Steve Zappa                  XXXXXXXXX
Frank Vai                    XXXXXXXXX
Yuzo Shimomura               XXXXXXXXX
```

Is this even possible? I got better results by left justifying the last name and right justifying the number like this

```
ps.printf("%s %-12s",bankarray[count].getFirst(),bankarray[count].getLast());
ps.printf("%17d",bankarray[count].getSoNumber());
```

but that only got me so far.

```
Account holder   Social security number
Steve jensen         XXXXXXXXX
Mary Chapman        XXXXXXXXX
Steve Zappa          XXXXXXXXX
Frank Vai            XXXXXXXXX
Yuzo Shimomura      XXXXXXXXX
```

There has to be a clear way that I'm just not seeing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem

The problem is that the padding in `%s %-12s` only pads the last attribute (`bankarray[count].getLast()`). If you test do the following code it will give you correctly aligned texts, even though the strings are of different length.

**Code**

```java
System.out.printf("%s %-12s", "Firstname", "Last");
System.out.printf("%17d%n", 123456789);
System.out.printf("%s %-12s", "Firstname", "Lastname");
System.out.printf("%17d%n", 123456789);
```

**Output**

```
Firstname Last                123456789
Firstname Lastname            123456789
```

However the following will mess it up, because the first attribute isn't padded.

**Code**

```java
    System.out.printf("%s %-12s", "First", "Lastname");
    System.out.printf("%17d%n", 123456789);
    System.out.printf("%s %-12s", "Firstname", "Lastname");
    System.out.printf("%17d%n", 123456789);
```

**Output**

```
First Lastname            123456789
Firstname Lastname            123456789
```

## The solution

I am not entirely sure it is possible to pad 2 strings simultaneously with `printf`, so I would suggest concatenate `bankarray[count].getFirst()` and `bankarray[count].getLast()` outside the `printf` statement.

```java
String name = String.format("%s %s", bankarray[count].getFirst(), bankarray[count].getLast());

ps.printf("%s-12s", name);
ps.printf("%17d", bankarray[count].getSoNumber());
```

### Extra: Padding the card number

You don't need to pad the card number if you're padding the name since it will just push away the card number from the position where the previous pad ended. This should be sufficient (and the same thing):

```java
String name = String.format("%s %s", bankarray[count].getFirst(), bankarray[count].getLast());

// Added 12+17=29 as padding
ps.printf("%s-29s", name);
// Removed padding enteirely
ps.printf("%d", bankarray[count].getSoNumber());
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. Concatenating the strings works a lot better and yes, there is no need to right justify the number if the name is left justified. Thanks, Johan.

Comment: Cheers, no problem @H.i